# PHP printing string

Tags: php, html

I am using var_dump for printing a variable, named $info. Now I need to print message_id as shown below, but the string is not getting print.

```
object(stdClass)[10]
  public 'date' => string 'Sun, 14 Oct 2012 19:45:26 +0100' (length=31)
  public 'Date' => string 'Sun, 14 Oct 2012 19:45:26 +0100' (length=31)
  public 'subject' => string 'deposit' (length=7)
  public 'Subject' => string 'deposit' (length=7)
  public 'message_id' => string '<CAKvS7sNb0Cb1AaAbCdEFGHerp5UyJuhfkcJj8P+8CZQj4VTGLA@mail.gmail.com>' (length=68)
  public 'toaddress' => string 'sbsa secretaccount <test@gmail.com>' (length=43)
```

I'm using this line,

```
echo $info->message_id;
```

Also if I try this,

```
$temp =  '<CAKvS7sNb0Cb1AaAbCdEFGHerp5UyJuhfkcJj8P+8CZQj4VTGLA@mail.gmail.com>';
echo "::$temp::";
```

Only :::: is getting printed, the $temp variable is ignored? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an object, not an array. Use:

```
echo $info->message_id;
```

[php.net - Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

In response to your second point - as the string is encapsulated in `<` and `>`, the browser will try and display this as HTML, if you view the source of the page, you will see that your `$temp` string is in there.

You could use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in order to convert the characters to HTML entities:

```
echo htmlentites($temp);
```

Comment: Can you figure out any reason for the echo problem, why the $temp is not getting printed?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what deifwud said about you having an *object* and not an *array* (they aren't interchangeable like they are in JavaScript), you should also note that anything of the form `<blah blah blah>` is seen by the browser as an HTML tag and is not displayed raw. If you go to View Source you will see it's right there. To avoid this problem, use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with both @deifwud and @Kolink.  Your string should be :

```
   $temp = htmlspecialchars('<CAKvS7sNb0Cb1AaAbCdEFGHerp5UyJuhfkcJj8P+8CZQj4VTGLA@mail.gmail.com>');
   echo "::$temp::";
```

That will escape the < and >  so that browser don't intreprate them like tag.